# Parsing date in PHP handler

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to parse this date with php 
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 06:33:06 +0200 to "27-07-2018 06:33:06" 
Is there a php function or class that handles this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime is your friend.

```
$date = new DateTime('Fri, 27 Jul 2018 06:33:06 +0200');
echo date_format($date,'m-d-Y h:i:s');
```